# Selenium has a problem finding element at lower window size (DOM doesn't change)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**little introduction:**
I'm using Selenium webdriver for Java to run some Tests. I got a Monitor with FullHD resolution (1920x1080) and a UWQHD Monitor (3440x1440). Normally i run selenium via chromedriver with headless as chrome param (which works fine so far). But if I want to develop or debug some Selenium paths, I use it without headless (of course).

Chromedriver Version: 77
Chrome Version: 78.0.3904.97

**the Problem:**
If I run the application without headless param on my fullHD Monitor selenium **fails to find elements**. If I run it on my UWQHD Monitor with a higher window size like 2500x1200 it works. The DOM really doesnt change between these window sizes. Also I can't set a higher window size then the current resolution of the monitor via:

```
this.driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(2500,1500));
```

Do you guys have any idea? I thought the window size is only important for the different DOMs.
Even If I track the selenium paths at a lower window size it won't work.

regards,
bierat

Comment: Is the problem really in the findElement() method or in the interaction methods? Imho finding the element should not be a problem independently on the window size, something like clicking might be a problem since the element might be scrolled into view first.

Comment: it seems to happen only at click commands. but especially at click event on radio buttons, submit buttons doesnt seems to be a problem. Mostly i get an error because the radio buttons (required fields) aren't selected/clicked and the submit button was pressed. 

I wonder why the view should be relevant at this point, since the click command also have targets to locate the element in the DOM like via xpath or css selectors.

Comment: Well if you findElement() and it does not exit with an exception then there is no problem finding the element. The problem is the interaction for which the element has to be visible on the screen. Try doing the following:     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);  (element is the result of your findElement() method)

Comment: Your hint helped me. actually I already used scrollintoview, but the problem was there is a sticky header which overlaps the element I want to be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that there was an sticky header which overlapped the element I wanted to be clicked.

So I set an offset to fix that issue and that solved it.
Thanks to Volokh for his hint!